# Why div tag content does not hide? Whereas p tag conents hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Why div content does not hide?</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why div content will hide . you are calling hide function on `p tag`

Comment: Are you serious? You're asking why clicking on a `<div>` doesn't trigger the event handler attached to `<p>` elements?

Comment: Sorry, Skipped the point. A big blunder by me.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient research effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` won't hide because you are using `p` in your selector, and later, you are using `$(this).hide()` so it will hide all the `p` elements because your `this` keyword references ALL the `p` elements in your document, so inorder to select the specific ones, you should always use an `id` or you can use `class` with `this` keyword.

It is better you assign an `id` to your `div` element, use a `button` element, and than hide specific elements like...

```
<div id="hide-this">
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
    <button>Hide the content</button>
</div>

$('#id-here button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujeXV/)</kbd>

Now obviously this will hide the button as well, so instead shift the button outside, and use `toggle()`

```
<div id="hide-this">
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
</div>
<button>Hide</button>

$("button").on('click', function(){
  $("#hide-this").toggle();
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujeXV/1/)</kbd>

---

If you want to toggle the button text, you will need `if` condition to compare the string of your `button` element...

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
  $("#hide-this").toggle();
    if($(this).text() == 'Hide') { //$(this) references button element here
        $(this).text('Show');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujeXV/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Great!!!!!  Thanks   I h'v Just started Javascript learning.

Comment: @Optimight If you started JavaScript learning, you shouldn't learn jQuery :)